# How to run scheduler in cluster environment using spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Email is triggering one time  in single node server. But it is duplicating multiple Email's in clustering environment because multiple nodes server are running. But need to get single Email in clustering environment. How to handle that in spring application.

```
@Service
public class MailController {

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 20 20 * * *")
    @Transactional("myTraxManger")
    public void sendmail() {
        System.out.println("Sending maill to User");
    }

}
```

Comment: Check Shedlock or Quartz for Cluster environment. They are simple to use.

Comment: thank u pawel... i have implemented Shedlock.it's working fine in cluster environment.

Comment: Glad to hear its working :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a framework such as [Spring Cloud](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/) or [Hazelcast](https://hazelcast.com/) to manage your cluster state and then you can decide to run scheduled tasks on only one of the nodes such as the leader with Leadership election.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have queuing solution like ActiveMQ or kafka and all clusters are going to put messages to queue and async mail sender process to get from that queue and send email.

Comment: thanks valuable reply but i want to run scheduler one time but this scheduler running multiple times.sendMail is process getting data from Backed also.